# How can I hide the "Turn on your speakers to hear the meeting" message in MS Teams on web?

Tags: microsoft-teams

How can I hide the "Turn on your speakers to hear the meeting" message in MS Teams on web (https://teams.microsoft.com/)?

E.g.:

[image]